# How to get file hash name in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

In `Angular 4` I've used `Webpack`'s (or even `File-loader`'s) require method to get Image hash name:

```
const versionedName = require('assets/images/icn-copy.svg');
```

It returns something like "`assets/images/icn-copy.435435fj5435f345345f435f435f345f.svg`" - hashed file name. And I could use it for request to server.
But after migration to `Angular 6` require function started returning object with property "`default`" that contains **not** hashed name.

How can I get hashed name in `Angular 6` and later?

**Update:**
I've noticed that images after migration are not hashed at all now. It may be the reason. For example

```
.loader {
    background-image: url('assets/images/spinner.svg');
...
}
```

results in just spinner.svg in the root instead of `spinner.214312fe21fe412f4ef.svg`

**Update 2**:
As the issue is solved now, I would appreciate to hear about better way to bypass caching for images though. `require()` is definitely **not** the best way. It is not about images from assets. It is about requested ones. For example:

```
this.http.get('assets/images/spinner.svg') // will be cached
this.http.get('assets/images/spinner.214312fe21fe412f4ef.svg') // will NOT be cached.
```

Comment: That is not what you use the assets folder for. Those files are not part of the WebPack bundle, and you're just forcing WebPack to include them. The asset folder is for files you want to be accessible from the web server as static files.

Comment: @Reactgular I don't include them to assets folder at all. I just need the unique name to prevent caching when fetch an icon. And it worked fine in Angular 4/5

Comment: @Reactgular do you have any other idea? Share please. And I'm still don't get the complete understandion of that file-loader's require(). It is completely another require that CommonJS one, as it returns hashed file name, but not entire file. If you think it is a bad idea, what is this require() used for instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that starting from `Angular 6` the hashing is disabled by default. Adding flag `--output-hashing=all` solved the issue. It is good to mention, that In `Typescript 2.7` now 
allowed default imports to CommonJS/AMD/UMD (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-from-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop).
It means that `require()` now returns not string with full file name but `object` with property default containing this `string`.
Instead of

```
icn-copy.435435fj5435f345345f435f435f345f.svg
```

now:

```
{
    default: "icn-copy.435435fj5435f345345f435f435f345f.svg"
}
```

But I still need better solution! (look update 2)